# New activitiy - The application does not start

Tags: android, android-activity

I added second activity to my application and i wrote this in AndroidManifest.xml but i still heve a problem. i don't know how i can solve it. I'm sure my source code is correct because i rewrite it from book.
 My logcat:

```
 09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.przyklad.sudoku/org.przyklad.sudoku.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at org.przyklad.sudoku.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
09-24 15:41:16.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5735):     ... 11 more
```

This is MainActivity.java

```
   package org.przyklad.sudoku;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Konfigurujemy obiekty nasłuchujące kliknięć dla wszystkich przycisków
        View przyciskKontynuacja = findViewById(R.id.przycisk_kontynuacja);
        przyciskKontynuacja.setOnClickListener(this);
        View przyciskNowa = findViewById(R.id.przycisk_nowa);
        przyciskNowa.setOnClickListener(this);
        View przyciskInformacje = findViewById(R.id.przycisk_informacje);
        przyciskInformacje.setOnClickListener(this);
        View przyciskWyjscie = findViewById(R.id.przycisk_wyjscie);
        przyciskWyjscie.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.przycisk_informacje:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Informacje.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

and Informacje.java

```
package org.przyklad.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Informacje extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.informacje);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your source code isn't correct. You're getting a nullpointerexception in the onCreate() of MainActivity. Post that method.

Comment: Please upload your code as well.

Comment: You are getting `NullPoinerException` on line 19 of `MainActvity.java`.  Post your code so we could get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't trust books. They are full of letters and stuff.

Also, as your stacktrace suggests (read it, there are tons of good stuff in it. More than in your book, it would seem), you have a null reference and you try to call a method on it. The call is located in MainActivity, line 19. That is in the onCreate method.

Most likely, it is a view reference that was not found for a reason. Possibly, you forgot to call setContentView